# Send to multiple ID

Tags: php, string, var

I'm writing a script where I want to send a notification to multiple users.

Works well when I have only one user id ... but I want to be able to send to several.

```
$userid = 3;
$um_notifications->api->store_notification( $userid, 'new_action', $vars )
```

The above works when it's just id "3" .. But if I want to send 3 & 4, I do not get it to work.

I have tested

```
$userid = 3,4;
```

and

```
$userid = "3,4";
```

and

```
$userid = array( '3', '4');
```

But then it will not be sent to anyone ..

What have I missed?

Comment: What does the function `$um_notifications->api->store_notification()` expect as a parameter?  If it's looking for a single user ID, then you send it a single user ID.  To perform this action multiple times you'd make multiple calls to that function.

Comment: What is `$um_notifications`, we can't help you without knowing what API/library you're using to send notifications.

Comment: You might want to try storing the list of user ids in an array (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Then you could iterate over the array using something like a for each (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make array of values and loop through it

```
$userid = [3,4];

foreach($users as $u){

$um_notifications->api->store_notification( $u, 'new_action', $vars );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array and cycle threw it. Something like this:

```
<?php
$userid = array(3,4);
foreach($userid as $id){
    $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $id, 'new_action', $vars );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define an array of id like this :

```
$ids=array(3,7,1);
```

Next you just need to have a loop on this id's array and send your notification :

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
       $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $id, 'new_action', $vars )
}
```